# Problema para visualizar gráficos em rmarkdown: Error in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png"... não é possível iniciar dispositivo png()

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Uso R em Rstudio. Sempre que tento gerar gráficos no `rmarkdown`, independente do comando utilizado (`plot()`, `boxplot()`, etc), aparece um erro e não inicia o dispositivo para mostrar o gráfico.

Um exemplo:

```
.libPaths("C:/Users/Marcella/Doc")
path.expand("C:/Users/Marcella/Doc")

> library(readxl)
> library(rmarkdown)

> dados = read_xlsx("C:/Users/Marcella/Doc/teste.xlsx")

> dados$Tratamento = as.factor(dados$Tratamento)

> dados$VT <- (log(dados$V1+1))
 
> layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE))
```

O erro:

```
Warning in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  :
          unable to open file 'C:/Users/Sérgio/AppData/Local/RStudio/notebooks/-Modelomisto/1/FD839925F447BF89/c2cyx1ksu87d7_t/_rs_chunk_plot_001.png' for writing
        Warning in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  :
          opening device failed
        Error in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  : 
          não é possível iniciar dispositivo png()
```

Portanto, queria saber se é possível alterar a pasta temporária que o R utiliza pra gerar os gráficos, pois como podem ver eu nem tentei salvar o gráfico, apenas criar.

Eu tenho quase certeza que este erro é devido ao tamanho e caracteres do nome da pasta temporária em que o R está gerando o arquivo. Mas apenas mudando os caminhos do diretório e da livraria não funciona para corrigir o erro que aparece quando gero gráficos.

```
> dput(dados)
    structure(list(Tratamento = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B"), V1 = c(17.53, 12.65, 8.9, 5.84, 5.2, 4.72, 16.14, 8.78)), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Oi Marcella! Tenta incluir as informações sugeridas por Marcus Nunes. Também tenta fazer a pergunta mais clara indicando o código que estás usando para salvar os gráficos. Poderias usar dados disponíveis do R e gerar um código simples para outras pessoas entenderem o teu problema. Para problemas similares ao teu, pode ser valioso ter informações básicas da sessão (`sessionInfo()`)

Comment: O que acontece se você modifica as opções de Rstudio para Rmarkdown? a) Deselecionar "Show output inline for all R Markdown"
b) "Show equation and image previews": 'In a popup'
c) "Evaluate chunks in directory": 'Document'

Comment: Com essas modificações o erro não é mais exibido! 
Eu só gostaria que os outputs continuassem aparecendo no RMarkdown, mas se não é possível.... pelo menos dessa forma consigo rodar o código sem problemas!  Muito obrigada

Comment: Você está escrevendo um documento "rmarkdown" ou "r-notebook"? Você especifica o diretório para trabalhar em cada sessão? Em relação a sua pergunta você pode usar [`fig_path`](https://rdrr.io/cran/knitr/man/fig_path.html) no chunk inicial do documento para modificar o diretório ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "figure/")
```

Comment: Rmarkdown. O diretório eu não especifico, porém tive que alterar nas opções globais um caminho padrão diferente do que veio originalmente já que nesse continha caracteres especiais. O que eu preciso indicar toda sessão é o caminho da livraria (.libPaths) e o path.expand, se não ele utiliza a pasta original que dá erro. Isso eu não consegui alterar de forma definitiva. Assim como não consigo alterar o caminho que o comando utiliza na hora que vai gerar gráficos. Com o fig_path, volta a mostrar os outputs no rmarkdown, mas dessa forma volta o mesmo erro inicial ao gerar os gráficos.

Comment: José, não consigo te responder no chat pois não tenho a quantidade de reputação necessária. Sou nova aqui, não sei como funciona direito para ganhar reputação.

Answer (score 0):

O problema não é devido ao `.libPaths()` senão ao diretório usado na sessão. Nesse caso a solução é usar `setwd()` ao início da sessão:

```
setwd("~/Diretorio")
```

Ou trabalhar usando "Projects" no Rstudio:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-RStudio-Projects

Outra opção é modificar as seguintes opções para enviar o output ao console do R e os gráficos a uma janela separada:

Em Rstudio ("Tools" -> "Global options" -> "Rmarkdown"):

- "Show output inline for all R Markdown": retirar seleção
- "Show equation and image previews": 'In a popup'
- "Evaluate chunks in directory": Document